# Can't open USB stick

Tags: usb

When I put my USB in my laptop I get the following error, on the USB is some data what I must have is there a way to get this?

[image: This is the error what I get.]

Comment: Can you put that error message in your post so we can read it, in the pic it is to small.

Comment: @WildMan Save the screenshot in your computer and view it using eog or basically view it directly in the browser.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7NwU.png

Answer (score 1):

I cheked for problems in GParted, then I plugged the USB in and out and now it works again.